# Updating window.location with new images based off JS if statements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’m trying to refactor my already working application. https://besthaircolor.herokuapp.com/

App:  When user selects eyeColor and skinTone, a new html results page opens (window.location) and presents them their 3 best hair colors.

Goal: Currently, I have numerous html pages based on every possible result, ex. eyeColor: “Brown” skinTone :“Fair”, Submit, then window.location opens up a separate page of 3 images of best unique hair colors. I’m trying to find a way where there is just ONE html results (window.location)page and the only thing that updates from the dropdown selections are the photos (results).

I’m having a hard time researching what I’m trying to do because adding an img src to window.location wouldn't technically work if it's not clear where the img's will be on the results page correct?  I apologize if it’s confusing, I’m still a beginner. If anyone can point me in the right direction or  suggest any tutorials for what I’m trying to accomplish that would be helpful.

Unless, my code is perfectly fine the way it currently is but from my studies duplicate/redundant code is never good. If anyone can **kindly** let me know.

My index.js:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState === "interactive") {
    initApplication();
  }
}

var eyeColor = null;
function selectMenu1(value){
  eyeColor = value;
}

var skinTone = null;
function selectMenu2(value){
  skinTone = value;
}



function validate()  { 
  if (eyeColor && skinTone){
          // alert(`You selected ${eyeColor} eye colour and ${skinTone} skin tone.`);
      if (eyeColor=="brown" && skinTone=="fair"){
        window.location = "brown/brown_fair.html";
      } else if (eyeColor=="brown" && skinTone=="light"){
        window.location = "brown/brown_light.html";
      } else if (eyeColor=="brown" && skinTone=="medium"){
        window.location = "brown/brown_medium.html";
      } else if (eyeColor=="brown" && skinTone=="bronze"){
        window.location = "brown/brown_bronze.html";
      } else if (eyeColor=="brown" && skinTone=="tan"){
        window.location = "brown/brown_tan.html";
      } else if (eyeColor=="brown" && skinTone=="rich"){
        window.location = "brown/brown_rich.html";
      }   

      if (eyeColor=="blue" && skinTone=="fair"){
        window.location = "blue/blue_fair.html";
      } else if (eyeColor =="blue" && skinTone=="light"){
        window.location = "blue/blue_light.html";
      } else if (eyeColor =="blue" && skinTone=="medium"){
        window.location = "blue/blue_medium.html";
      } else if (eyeColor =="blue" && skinTone=="bronze"){
        window.location = "blue/blue_bronze.html";
      } else if (eyeColor=="blue" && skinTone=="tan"){
        window.location = "blue/blue_tan.html";
      } else if (eyeColor=="blue" && skinTone=="rich"){
        window.location = "blue/blue_rich.html";
      }

      if (eyeColor=="green" && skinTone=="fair"){
        window.location = "green/green_fair.html";
      } else if (eyeColor == "green" && skinTone=="light"){
        window.location= "green/green_light.html";
      } else if (eyeColor== "green" && skinTone=="medium"){
        window.location="green/green_medium.html";
      } else if (eyeColor=="green" && skinTone=="bronze"){
        window.location="green/green_bronze.html";
      } else if (eyeColor=="green" && skinTone=="tan"){
        window.location="green/green_tan.html";
      } else if (eyeColor=="green" && skinTone=="rich"){
        window.location="green/green_rich.html";
      }


      if (eyeColor=="hazel" && skinTone=="fair"){
        window.location = "hazel/hazel_fair.html";
      } else if (eyeColor=="hazel" && skinTone=="light"){
        window.location="hazel/hazel_light.html";
      } else if (eyeColor=="hazel" && skinTone=="medium"){
        window.location="hazel/hazel_medium.html";
      } else if (eyeColor=="hazel" && skinTone=="bronze"){
        window.location="hazel/hazel_bronze.html";
      } else if (eyeColor=="hazel" && skinTone=="tan"){
        window.location="hazel/hazel_tan.html";
      } else if (eyeColor=="hazel" && skinTone=="rich"){
        window.location="hazel/hazel_rich.html";
      }
    }




//Error message if user does not select an item from the dropdown menus

if (!eyeColor){
  document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "<span class='error'>Please choose an eye color</span>";
}
else if (!skinTone){
  document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "<span class='error'>Please choose a skin tone</span>";
}
}

      function initApplication(){
        //setup dropdown menu selection events
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-menu")).forEach((menu,idx)=>{
          const menuCallbackName = menu.attributes.onchange.value;
          const fetchedCallback = window[menuCallbackName] || null;

          if (fetchedCallback){
            Array.from(menu.children).forEach((child)=>{
              const callbackValue = child.attributes.data ? child.attributes.data.value : null;
              if (callbackValue) child.onclick = () => fetchedCallback(callbackValue);
            });
          } else console.error(`No callback function named ${menuCallbackName} for menu ${idx}`);

        });
      }
```

my index.html:

```
<title>Best Hair Color</title>
```

```
<!--Intro-->

<div class="container text-center">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-4" style="font-size: 2.5rem;"><i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i> Your Best Hair Color Is . . .</h1>
        <hr class="my-4">
        <p class="info">"The most flattering hair color comes when you have "THE PERFECT TRIO". A perfect trio is when your hair color matches your skin tone and eye color. Your perfect hair color will make your eyes POP. Your eyes will appear brighter and bigger. It will also go well with your skin tone. The right hair color will give your skin color, vibrance, and softness." <a href="http://salonenvychicago.com/" target="_blank"> - Salone Envy Chicago</a></p>

    </div>

    <!--Drop down Item 1 -->

    <h3 class="display-4" style="font-size: 1.5rem;">What is your eye color</h3>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="input-group justify-content-center">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-md dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="background-color: #588c7e;">
                    Eye Color

                </button>

                <div class="dropdown-menu" onchange="selectMenu1"  aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" id="eyeColor">
                    <a class="dropdown-item"  data="brown" ><img src="img/brown_eye.jpg" class="rounded-circle"> Brown</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item"  data="blue" ><img src="img/blue_eye.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Blue</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" data="green" ><img src="img/green_eye.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Green</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item"  data="hazel" ><img src="img/hazel_eye.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Hazel</a>
                </div>



            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Drop down Item 2-->

    <h3 class="display-4" style="font-size: 1.5rem;"> What is your skin tone</h3>
    <div id="menu2" class="dropdown">
        <div class="input-group justify-content-center">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-md dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="background-color: #588c7e;">
                    Skin Tone
                </button>

                <div class="dropdown-menu" onchange="selectMenu2" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" id="skinTone">
                    <a class="dropdown-item"  data="fair"><img src="img/fair.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Fair</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item"  data="light"><img src="img/light.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Light</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" data="medium"><img src="img/medium.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Medium</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item"  data="bronze"><img src="img/bronze_dark.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Bronze</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item"  data="tan"><img src="img/tan.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Tan</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" data="rich"><img src="img/dark.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Rich</a>
                </div>

                <div class="error" id="error"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <!--Result Button-->
    <label id="error"></label>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg active" title ="Submit" style="background-color: #3e4444;" onclick="validate()"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right fa-lg"></i></button>


    <script>
        $(".dropdown-menu a ").click(function(){
            $(this).parents(".input-group-btn").find('.btn').text($(this).text());
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe what you want to do is change the image `src` and the result text instead of use `window.location` to redirect the page to another html page.  Is this right?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to update the images based off the users selections and the results only being assigned to just (1) .html page rather than the dozen I have.

Comment: well you could have all the possible different color combinations of hair in `n` hidden div's (where `n` is the number of all different possibilities) then toggle the visibility of the right one depending on the colors chosen.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to improve your code, but if you are specifically looking to clean up your redundancies, you can clean up all your selection functions with something like this:

```
function getColor (eyeColor, skinTone) {
  window.location = eyeColor + "/" + eyeColor + "_" + skinTone + ".html";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code is already working, you can replace the redundant code this way:

```
window.location = `{eyeColor}/{eyeColor}_{skinTone}.html`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you with two solutions,

1. With the same set of pages,rather than redirecting the whole page make use you of  Iframe to load whatever page you want inside the Iframe
2. The way I do:
   Use image tag  and feed it with whatever image source you want as a byte array.

Comment: Please paste code snippets to make it fruitful for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

So basically what I was suggesting was something like:

```
<!--index.html-->

<!--after result-button-->
<div id="brown_fair" style="display:hidden">
  <!-- here goes your brown/brown_fair.html content, or what you want of it-->
</div>
<!--one more div for each possible result-->
```

and in your javascript:

```
function validate()  { 
  if (eyeColor && skinTone){
          // alert(`You selected ${eyeColor} eye colour and ${skinTone} skin tone.`);
      if (eyeColor=="brown" && skinTone=="fair") {
        //toggle element visibility
        document.getElementById("brown_fair").style.display(desiredDisplay);
      }

      //...
   }
}
```